# How to install symfony2 project existing in github repository to local instance

Tags: symfony, github

I'm having a symfony2 project in github repository. I want to install it to my local instance. I'm using Xampp on Windows 7. How can I achieve it?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your using xampp the easiest way is to use symfony build in server.
clone or download the symfony project to your xampp htdocs. 
start your xampp and open the shell, (shell button on the right)

locate yourself in the root symfony dir. and type:

```
php app/console server:run
```

a local php server should start on `http://localhost:8000`

i recomment using this because (dev mode is loaded by default).
its faster then a VM because you dont sync files.
 you can also add verbose arguments

```
php app/console server:run -vvv
```

that way you get more output info when debugging.